# bootstrapping AHAH without full page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal, ahah

I've written some modal box functionality that loads HTML into the DOM as snippets. This includes AHAH-enabled forms.

I've got as far as pulling out the AHAH settings, and can re-initialize:

```
jQuery.extend( Drupal.settings, response.setting );
```

I can also re-initialize:

```
Drupal.attachBehaviors( container );
```

I've even ensured that ahah.js is always loaded into the main page.

All this doesn't seem to be enough to get it working.
Does anyone know what else I need to do?

Comment: also ensuring that jquery.form.js is loaded.
I can get as far as getting the AHAH response, but the callback doesn't fire to load into the wrapper

Comment: I think I've sorted it.
The ahah.js ajax call has no error callback. it was failing silently, but the fault was in my response json.

Comment: You should post your own solution as an answer and eventually accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The steps in my initial question are actually fine. This is all you need to do to get AHAH kick-started into a custom bit of JS. As I said in my comment the AHAH JavaScript has no error callback, so put some breakpoints in ahah.js if things don't seem to be working as expected.